# Looking for a command line ftp client that can upload entier folder

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, ftp

I need something like Filezilla that does the same thing in a console. The default ftp client on Ubuntu can only upload files, mput doesn't seem to work on folders. I have many folders and sub folders and doing so via command line is a pain. Also scp etc is not an option for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `ncftp` and its `ncftpput -R` command.

Comment: Cool! It even comes by default. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for this tool for ages, I used it in 2006 and I forgot its name, now here it is!

Answer (score 3):

`lftp` in conjunction with the `mirror -R` command.

Answer (score 1):

The ncftp family is a very slick and powerful command line client that supports everything you want including interactive and batch jobs.